# Proving an irrational number in the cantor set

Tags: real-analysis

I'm trying to prove that $0.2020020002\ldots_3 \in \Bbb Q^c\cap C$ where $C$ denotes the Cantor set. I'm trying to get a contradiction assuming $0.2020020002\ldots_3 \in \Bbb Q$ (without using the fact that every rational number is periodic or terminating).

Suppose $$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{2}{3^{\frac{k(k+1)}{2}}}=\frac{p}{q}.$$

Choose $n$ such that $3^n \gt q+1$. Then $$ q \times3^n\times \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{2}{3^{\frac{k(k+1)}{2}}}= p \times 3^n=integer.$$ I'm stuck after this step. How can I show that this is an integer between $0$ and $1$?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Hint: Choose $n=\frac{K(K+1)}{2}$ so that $0.\underbrace{0\cdots0}_{n \mbox{ zeros}}20222\dots<\frac{1}{q}$. Then $3^n\cdot q\cdot\mbox{(your number)}$ will be greater than some integer by an amount strictly between 0 and 1, and therefore cannot be an integer.

Comment: But then $3^n \cdot q \cdot 0.\underbrace{0\cdots0}_{n \mbox{ zeros}}02020020002 \cdots = p \lt 3^n.$ How can I deduce anything from this?

Comment: You're looking at the wrong quantity. You need to look at $3^n\cdot q\cdot\mbox{(your number)}$. First, since $n$ is of the form $\frac{K(K+1)}{2}$, $3^n\cdot\mbox{(your number)}$ looks like 

[some digits ending in 2][decimal point][at least $\frac{(K)(K+1)}{2}$ zeros]$20$[more digits].

(Multiplication by $3^n$ shifts the decimal place by $n$ places.) This is an integer plus a number less than $\frac{1}{q}$. Then $3^n\cdot q\cdot\mbox{(your number)}$, which is an integer multiple of $p$, turns out not to be able to be an integer.

Comment: Don't you mean that $3^n \cdot \mbox{(my number)}$ [some digits ending in 2][decimal point][at least $K$ zeroes]20[more digits]. Because your formula does not work for K=3($3^6 \cdot 0.2020020002 \cdots=202002.0002 \cdots$) which has only 3 zeroes after the decimal point(as opposed to 6 in your formula).

Answer (score 0):

Ok, this isn't your exact number, but your number does look similar to [Liouville's number](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liouville_number)

Does the technique given there work for your case? It seems like it should. (2*Liouville's number would obviously work for you too.)

Comment: I checked the link you sent and I don't understand what $p$ and $q$ are.

Comment: okay. Now I get what $p$ and $q$ are but we can't have the same inequalities $0 \gt |x- \frac{p}{q}| \lt \frac{1}{q^n}$ now can we?

Comment: Honestly, your number is obviously non-repeating, and therefore cannot be rational. You could center a proof around that concept and probably be done pretty quickly. (Which would be a valid mathematical proof, by the way)
See here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/287402/is-a-non-repeating-and-non-terminating-decimal-always-an-irrational

Comment: We were asked to find a different method to prove it. :-(

Answer (score 0):

Suppose $$ \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{2}{3^{\frac{k(k+1)}{2}}} \text{ is rational.}$$ Then there exists $ p,q\in \mathbb{Z}^{+} $ such that  $\gcd(p,q)=1$ and

$$ \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{2}{3^{\frac{k(k+1)}{2}}}=\frac{p}{q} .$$

Then you need to choose $ n\in \mathbb{N} $ such that $ n=\frac{k_{0}(k_{0}+1)}{2} $ for some $ k_{0}\in \mathbb{N} $ with $ 3^{k_{0}}>q+1 $.

Put $$ x=q3^{n}\left( \frac{p}{q}-\sum_{k=1}^{k_{0}}\frac{2}{3^{\frac{k(k+1)}{2}}}\right). $$
Then $$x=3^{n}p-q3^{n}\sum_{k=1}^{k_{0}}\frac{2}{3^{\frac{k(k+1)}{2}}}. $$
Hence $x$ is an integer.

Observe that $$x=q3^{n}\sum_{k=k_{0}+1}^{\infty}\frac{2}{3^{\frac{k(k+1)}{2}}}>0. $$
Therefore $x$ is a positive integer.

Also observe that $$x=q3^{n}\sum_{k=k_{0}+1}^{\infty}\frac{2}{3^{\frac{k(k+1)}{2}}}<q3^{n}\sum_{k=k_{0}+1}^{\infty}\frac{2}{3^{n+k}}<q\sum_{k=k_{0}+1}^{\infty}\frac{2}{3^{k}}=\frac{q}{3^{k_{0}}}<\frac{q+1}{3^{k_{0}}}<1. $$
That is $x$ is a positive integer with $ x<1 $. So we have a contradiction.